# How to continue keydown event after keyup was triggered

Tags: javascript, events, keydown, keyup

I am making this game (invaders clone). I want to move ship left and right, and when control is pressed the ship will shoot.
The problem is when is release control, the ship stops moving.
i have bind this function to keydown:

```
checkKey: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = true;
        e.preventDefault();
        GAME.respond();         
    }
```

and this to keyup:

```
clearKey: function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if (e.keyCode in map) {
        map[e.keyCode] = false;
    }               
    if (e.keyCode === 17){
        GAME.respond();
    }
```

GAME.respond() looks like this:

```
respond: function(){
    console.log("map", map);
    if (map[17]) {
            SHIP.shoot();
        }
        if (map[37]) {
            SHIP.move(LEFT);
            return;
        }
        if (map[39]) {
            SHIP.move(RIGHT);
            return;
        }
        if (map[38]) {
            SHIP.move(UP);
            return;
        }
        if (map[40]) {
            SHIP.move(DOWN);
            return;
        }
},
```

Keys pressed are mapped via the map object (declared elsewhere).
The problem is after keyup event has been triggered, even when arrow keys are still down nothing happens. How can I restore following pressed keys?

Comment: Have a look at Phaser.js Invaders example, the way its implemented should give you a hint on how to do yours. http://phaser.io/examples/v2/games/invaders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most games ive seen, the movement keys are put in the gameloop. Meaning it checks the keymap each loop and moves accordingly, and you've put your movement keys in respond. Another thing I know is that if you press a key and hold it repeats the keypress down, until you press another key down. Which means it will only repeat the last keypress. So it would be better if you checked the state in the loop instead of an event basis.

Comment: Indeed, that was the only thing that worked - game loop. Now it works perfectly.